# How to stretch the container view below the statusBar in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Navigation stack with one tab navigation nested in it. On the iPhone they view with style flex 1 fills the whole screen, while on android the view goes as far as the status bar. I want the view to fill the entire screen.
And it works fine on Iphone.

```
 render() {
    return(
        <View style={Style.cont}>

        </View>
    )
}


}
export default Profile
const Style = StyleSheet.create({
cont:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#1f2125',

}
})
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBK1k.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBK1k.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIL2Z.png)[image]

Comment: Please add more details of what you have tried and what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: I’ve edited it. Can you have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I hadto use StatusBar provided by expo.
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar' instead of import {StatusBar} from 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding the status bar component and give it the required background-colour

https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar